# VB.net multiple dims = true at same time?

Tags: vb.net, boolean

I have this code:

```
Dim name, surname As Boolean
    surname, name = False
```

It doesnt work, is there a way for my above code to work? I looked everywhere and cant seem to find a suitable fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported in VB.net.

You are stuck with:

```
Dim name As Boolean = False
Dim surname As Boolean = False
```

`Boolean` is initialized `False` by default, so if that's the value you want, there is no need to set them `False` explicitly at initialization.

If you declare it inside a loop, like the code below, be careful, because it will only be initialized once.  Only the first `Console.WriteLine` in the first iteration will output `False`.  If you want it to be initialized each time, you have to do `Dim a As Boolean = False`.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    Dim a As Boolean
    Console.WriteLine(a)
    a = True
    console.WriteLine(a)
Next
```

**Output:**

```
False
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
```

Comment: So i have to go: name = false and surname = false? No way to make it quicker and easier?

Comment: Oh really? I honestly didnt know that, let me try this out then and if that IS the case then wow. I have no worry completing my code haha cheers!

Comment: I've added some more notes to my answer for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! What a rookie mistake in my behalf! Thanks again:)